# Parametrizing a complex path

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

So I have the set $a=\{x+iy|y=x^3-3x^2+4x-1\}$ that connects $1+i$ and $2+3i$.

> How do I parametrize a complex path of this?

Eventually I want to find $\int_a(12z^2-4iz)dz$ and it seemed to me the best way was to parametrize a path, but I wouldn't know how. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: The integrand is analytic, so the integral is independent of path. So you should just use a different path, eg. the straight line path.

Comment: @AdamHughes Is there a theorem that allows me to do so?

Comment: Yes, it's the one that says integrals of analytic functions along paths in simply connected domains are independent of path, which follows as a corollary to the one that says the integral along a closed path is 0.

Comment: @AdamHughes Thankyou, does it also have a name?

Comment: Not that I know of. I suppose it's the complex version of the FTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i will try to solve this as a 2nd order integration by curve.

$\int_a (12x^2-12y^2+2ixy -4ix +4y)(dx+idy)$

$$
=\int_a (12x^2-12y^2+4y)dx+(-2xy+4x)dy + i\int_a(12x^2-12y^2+4y)dy+(2xy-4x)dx
$$

These two integrals **depend** on the path chosen since 
$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}\ne \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$

So i will take the path that you wanted

$\gamma(t)=(t,t^3−3t^2+4t−1)$  for  $t\in[1,2]$

That gives us the integral by substituting 
$x$ for $t$ , $y$ for $t^3−3t^2+4t−1$ ,
$dx$ for $1dt$,
$dy$ for $(3t^2-6t+4)dt$
And the borders are $ [1,2] \ni t$

There is some work to be done but the integral itself is easy.